# Neovim starting multiple LSP clients for each buffer

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I recently realized that my neovim automatically spawns the same language server (in this case, `tsserver` and `tailwindcss`) everytime I open a file.

Everything works fine when opening the first file
[image]

However, once I opened another file, it starts spawning another lsp client
[image]

Here's my nvim config for the lsp.

```lua
-- Mappings.
-- See `:help vim.diagnostic.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<space>e", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()<CR>", opts)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "[d", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>", opts)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "]d", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_next()<CR>", opts)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<space>q", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR>", opts)

-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, "omnifunc", "v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc")

    -- Mappings.
    -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gd", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>", opts)
end

local capabilities = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities(vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities())
local rawCapabilitiesWithoutFormatting = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
rawCapabilitiesWithoutFormatting.textDocument.formatting = false
rawCapabilitiesWithoutFormatting.textDocument.rangeFormatting = false
local capabilitiesWithoutFormatting = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities(rawCapabilitiesWithoutFormatting)

-- Use a loop to conveniently call 'setup' on multiple servers and
-- map buffer local keybindings when the language server attaches, for
-- servers that don't need any special treatment
local servers = {
    "bashls",
    "clangd",
    "cssls",
    "eslint",
    "gopls",
    "html",
    "jsonls",
    "rust_analyzer",
    "svelte",
    "tailwindcss",
    "vimls",
    "volar",
    "prismals",
    "marksman",
}
for _, lsp in pairs(servers) do
    require("lspconfig")[lsp].setup({
        on_attach = on_attach,
        flags = {
            debounce_text_changes = 300,
        },
        capabilities = capabilities,
    })
end

-- setup tsserver manually like a pro
require("lspconfig").tsserver.setup({
    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
        client.server_capabilities.document_formatting = false
        client.server_capabilities.document_range_formatting = false

        on_attach(client, bufnr)
    end,
    flags = {
        debounce_text_changes = 300,
    },
    capabilities = capabilitiesWithoutFormatting,
    settings = {
        documentFormatting = false,
    },
    root_dir = require("lspconfig.util").find_git_ancestor,
})

vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = vim.lsp.with(vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, {
    underline = true,
    -- This sets the spacing and the prefix, obviously.
    virtual_text = {
        spacing = 4,
    },
    signs = true,
    update_in_insert = true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue on `nvim-lspconfig`'s end, however it was fixed on a recent patch. Just pull in the latest version and it should work as expected.